# Error: done < <(find . -name "*.jar")

Tags: java, bash, maven, cygwin

I have a bash code which I run from cygwin from my windows computer. My team mates are running the following code perfectly in their computers but in my the following error comes up:

```
$ bash addmvn.sh
addmvn.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
'ddmvn.sh: line 6: `done < <(find . -name "*.jar")
```

Here is the code which we use to install maven to our project

```
while read line
do
    echo $line;
    jar=`basename $line`
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$line -DgroupId=com.strategyard.thirdparty -DartifactId=$jar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
done < <(find . -name "*.jar")
```

Comment: Are you in shell? Just use `bash` instead.

Comment: Try to use bash with this shebang `#!/bin/bash` instead of others (like `#!/bin/sh`) for example.

Comment: For your project use an aggregator pom and just do a single `mvn install`

Comment: Note the odd error message that starts `'ddmvm.sh` instead of `addmvn.ssh`; your script has DOS line endings, which need to be converted to UNIX line endings using `dos2unix` or `tr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is stored in DOS/Windows format, with a carriage return followed by linefeed (sometimes written "\r\n") at the end of each line; unix uses just a linefeed ("\n") at the end of lines, and so bash is mistaking the carriage return for part of the command. When it sees

```
while read line\r
do\r
```

it doesn't recognize "do\r" as a keyword, just a regular command, so it continues forward looking for the "do" keyword. When it sees "done" instead, it gets confused and gives the error you see.

BTW, the way I can tell this is the problem is from the error

```
'ddmvn.sh: line 6: `done < <(find . -name "*.jar")
```

Note that the close quote is at the beginning of the line, rather than the end. That tells me that the actual error is:

```
addmvn.sh: line 6: `done < <(find . -name "*.jar")\r'
```

... and the carriage return is sending it back to the beginning of the line so the close quote overwrites the "a" in the script name.

Solution: convert the script to unix format; I believe you'll have the dos2unix command available for this, but you might have to look around for alternatives. In a pinch, you can use

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n?/\n/g' /path/to/script
```

(see http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5088/convert-files-from-dos-line-endings-to-unix-line-endings). Then switch to a text editor that saves in unix format rather than DOS.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
while read line
do
        echo $line;
        jar=`basename $line`
        mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$line -DgroupId=com.strategyard.thirdparty -DartifactId=$jar -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
done <<< $(find . -name "*.jar")
```

Comment: The error indicates a shell without support for process substitution is being used, in which case a here string is unlikely to be recognized either.

Comment: So, I delete my question?